# JSON data embedded with images and text (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, json, swift

Hey guys I’m having a little trouble and i would like some help figuring it out. Im working with some JSON data. The JSON will return a paragraph and inside the paragraph it gives an image. Below ill show you the JSON result and how the CMS adds the image. So i added the body without image to a textview and thats works fine but if they embed a image it crashes. How do i show the image in the textview or skip the image and just put the content or something. Code examples please if u can

```
CMS
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
![Conference Centre]
//images.places.com/434432/4234328423rf234/Conference_Centre.jpg
more of the same
```

Now i will show you how the JSON is returned

```
JSON
“body" : "Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum\n\n![Conference Centre](\/\/images.places.com\/434432\/4234328423rf234\/Conference_Centre.jpg)\n\nmore of the same"
```

JSON Edited (I just added some spaces so you can see it better)

```
“body" : "Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum\n\n!
[Conference Centre]
(\/\/images.places.com\/434432\/4234328423rf234\/Conference_Centre.jpg)\n\n\ 
more of the same"
```

Comment: I pull the content and everything is fine. But if i ever embed an image the app crashes. Ive been trying to figure out where to start with this but cant come up with anything. Its weird how they embed the images in. Wish they had like different JSON results for that

Comment: If the app crashes, that means you tried something. Show us what you tried.